# Firebase deploy Error: database.rules is not of a type(s) object

Tags: json, firebase

I ran firebase init and made a project.

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }
}
```

When I run firebase deploy I get

```
=== Deploying to 'shippymcshipface'...

i  deploying database, hosting
+  database: rules ready to deploy.
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
+  hosting: 3 files uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...

Error: database.rules is not of a type(s) object
```

Which is weird since in the same directory I have database.rules.json autogenerated

```
"{\n  \"rules\": {\n    \".read\": true,\n    \"users\": {\n      \"usernames\": {\n        \"$username\":{\n          \".write\": true,\n        \t//\".write\": \"!data.exists() || !newData.exists()\",\n          \"chats\":{\n            \".write\": true\n          },\n          \"location\":{\n            \".write\": true\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    \"chats\": {\n      \".read\": true,\n      \".write\": true\n    },\n    \"messages\": {\n      \".read\": true,\n      \".write\": true\n    },\n    \"crushes\": {\n      \".read\": true,\n      \".write\": true\n    },\n    \"uids\": {\n      \".read\": true,\n      \".write\": true\n    },\n    \"ships\": {\n      \".read\": true,\n      \".write\": true\n    }\n  }\n}"
```

Not sure what is going on but I've tried multiple times, even copying the firebase rules from my database and making a new database.rules file. I've never run into this deploy problem in the past, any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your rules file content was pasted a bit weird, or if that's actually what the file looks like then there's your problem -- it's a JSON string instead of a JSON object.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thanks a bunch! That was totally the solution, I just copied and pasted the JSON object into a new file and had to change permissions and the deploy worked. The database.rules.json that was generated did not work and I didn't understand the error message. But now it works perfect very exciting! I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, it seems the generated ***database.rules.json*** file contains escape characters and new line chars like so:

> "\n// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your
>   app,\n// read and write access to your database\n{\n  \"rules\": {\n
>   \".read\": true,\n    \".write\": true\n  }\n}"

I just had to remove the comments / illegal characters to create a valid JSON file:

```
{"rules":
  {
    ".read":true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```